# How to collide with the window frame, bounce the ball and restrict the ball to the rectangular area?

Tags: python, vector, pygame, collision-detection

Hey i am trying to create a breakout clone with pygame, and i used

```
self.course(180 - self.course) % 360
```

To bounce the ball of the paddle, however i was looking into the vector 2 class, but i got no idea how to convert my Ball class using this. If anyone could guide me in the right direction.

here is my code that i want to convert using vector2.

```
import pygame
import math

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    course = 130

    def __init__(self):
        # Calling the parent class (Sprite)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Creating the ball and load the ball image
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 270

    # Creating a bounce function to make the ball bounce of surfaces.
    def bounce(self, diff):
        self.course = (180 - self.course) % 360
        self.course -= diff
        
    # Create the function that will update the ball.
    def update(self):
        course_radianse = math.radians(self.course)
        self.rect.x += 10 * math.sin(course_radianse)
        self.rect.y -= 10 * math.cos(course_radianse)
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y
        
        # Check if ball goes past top
        if self.rect.y <= 0:
            self.bounce(0)
            self.rect.y = 1
            
        # Check if ball goes past left side
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.course = (360 - self.course) % 360
            self.rect.x = 1
            
        # Check if ball goes past right side
        if self.rect.x >= 800:
            self.course = (360 - self.course) % 360
            self.rect.x = 800 - 1
            
        if self.rect.y > 600:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by using it?

Comment: I want to avoid using cos and sin, to get familiar using vector2 in pygame.
I belive i need to declare all my objects in using vector2 but i am not familiar with the procedure. Hope this answered your question

Answer (score 11):

A vector defines a direction and an amount. You have to add the vector to the location of the ball. Sadly `pygame.Rect` stores integral numbers only, so the location of the object has to be stored in a [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html), too. You need 1 vector for the location of the object and a 2nd one for the direction. Every time when the location changes, then the `.rect` attribute has to be set by the rounded location.
If the object hits a surface then the Ball is reflected ([.reflect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.reflect)) by the [Normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) to the surface.

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-BallBounceOffFrame](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-BallBounceOffFrame#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
import random

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, startpos, velocity, startdir):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(startpos)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.dir = pygame.math.Vector2(startdir).normalize()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))

    def reflect(self, NV):
        self.dir = self.dir.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.dir * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)
   
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_groups = pygame.sprite.Group()
start, velocity, direction = (250, 250), 5, (random.random(), random.random())
ball = Ball(start, velocity, direction)
all_groups.add(ball)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_groups.update()

    if ball.rect.left <= 100:
        ball.reflect((1, 0))
    if ball.rect.right >= 400:
        ball.reflect((-1, 0))
    if ball.rect.top <= 100:
        ball.reflect((0, 1))
    if ball.rect.bottom >= 400:
        ball.reflect((0, -1))

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (100, 100, 300, 300), 1)
    all_groups.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Lets assume you have a group of blocks:

```py
block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Detect the collision of the `ball` and the `block_group`. Once a collision ([`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)) is detected, `reflect` the ball on the block:

```py
block_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, block_group, False)
if block_hit:
    bl = block_hit[0].rect.left  - ball.rect.width/4
    br = block_hit[0].rect.right + ball.rect.width/4
    nv = (0, 1) if bl < ball.rect.centerx < br else (1, 0)
    ball.reflect(nv)
```